# RxJs make breakable request sequence

Tags: rxjs

I need to make a sequence of calls (the length of this sequence is variable) to an API. On each iteration I want to continue only if there is a success and if there is not return error to an observer. Also, these requests do not need any data from previous request.

Ho do I implement this request queue?

For now I see it as a method which is being called recursively until the end of request array.

```
sendQueue(list: any[]) {
    const {request, transferData} = list[0];
    this.send(request, transferData).subscribe(msg => {
        if (list.length > 0) {
            this.sendQueue(list.slice(1));
        } else {
            return of(true);
        }
    }, err => {
        this.ns.showError(err);
        return of(false);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat`. It will subscribe to each source Observable one after another and if any of them throws an error then it'll stop.

```
sendQueue(list: any[]) {
  const sources = list.map(({ request, transferData }) => this.send(request, transferData));
  return concat(...sources);
}
```